# How to spread data and combine into same row by same id in r

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I have a data looks like this:

```
Id Time       Type location  count  no_activities      id 
1  2014/10/11  A   level1      20     10              1
2  2014/10/11  B   level1      20     10              2
3  2014/10/11  C   level1      10      9              3
4  2014/10/11  A   level2      5      12              4
5  2014/10/11  B   level2      6       5              5
6  2014/10/11  C   level2      7       8              6
7  2014/10/11  A   level3      7       8              7
8  2014/10/11  B   level3      9       5              8
9  2014/10/11  C   level3      20     23              9
...
...
     Time       Type location count  no_activities      id 
101  2014/11/27  A   level33     20     10              101
102  2014/11/27  B   level33     30     10              102
103  2014/11/27  C   level33     10      9              103
104  2014/11/27  A   level34     10     12              104
105  2014/11/27  B   level34     16      5              105
106  2014/11/27  C   level34     5       8              106
107  2014/11/27  A   level35     3       8              107
108  2014/11/27  B   level35     1       5              108
109  2014/11/27  C   level35     10     23              109
```

After grouping them by date and location, I want to spread the `"Type"` column and combine the `"count"` of the same group(based on time and location) into the same row, like this:

```
Id Time        location     A  B  C 
1  2014/10/11   level1     20 20 10
4  2014/10/11   level2      5  6  7
7  2014/10/11   level3      7  9 20
10 2014/10/11   level4     ...
13 2014/10/11   level5     ...
16 2014/10/11   level6      
19 2014/10/11   level7         
22 2014/10/11   level8   
25 2014/10/11   level9      
...
```

I have read some similar questions but none seem to be solving my problem in this case. I tried these code:

```
df %>% dplyr::group_by(Time, location) %>% summarise_all(funs(toString(na.omit(.))))
```

which managed to group the observations by date and level but replaced whatever is missing in the columns with `NA` rather than combining the
rows of same time and level into one:

```
Id  Time        location  count  no_activities id    A   B  C
1  2014/10/11   level1      20     10         1    20  NA NA
2  2014/10/11   level1      20     10         2    NA  20 NA
3  2014/10/11   level1      10      9         3    NA  NA 10
4  2014/10/11   level2      5      12         4     5  NA NA
5  2014/10/11   level2      6       5         5    NA   6 NA
6  2014/10/11   level2      7       8         6    NA  NA  7
7  2014/10/11   level3      7       8         7     7  NA NA  
8  2014/10/11   level3      9       5         8    NA   9 NA 
9  2014/10/11   level3     20      23         9    NA  NA 20
...
```

I also tried

```
df %>%  reshape(df, v.names= c("A", "B", "C"), idvar=Id, timevar ="Time", direction="wide")
```

and

```
df %>%
group_by(Time, location) %>%
  spread(Type, count)
```

none of them worked. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Hi sorry there was a typo- the levels were repeated, whereas they should be same level with different counts for A,B and C. And I've changed the date.

Comment: @ Mauritz I think I see the problem now; The goal is to obtain `count` values for the `Type` variable to plot a correlation graph. Maybe I could just delete the other columns. Could you please advise how I could do this in r?

Comment: @Maurits sorry this is a bit confusing but I think it's both: I have to group them by (`Time`, `location`), in which case I have exactly one observation per `Time`, `location` and `Type`, then combine them into one row based on `Type`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further to the discussion in the comments above, do you mean something like this?

```
df %>%
    group_by(Time, location) %>%
    select(Time, location, Type, count) %>%
    spread(Type, count) %>%
    ungroup()
## A tibble: 6 x 5
#  Time       location     A     B     C
#  <fct>      <fct>    <int> <int> <int>
#1 2014/10/11 level1      20    20    10
#2 2014/10/11 level2       5     6     7
#3 2014/10/11 level3       7     9    20
#4 2014/11/27 level33     20    30    10
#5 2014/11/27 level34     10    16     5
#6 2014/11/27 level35      3     1    10
```

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
"Id Time       Type location  count  no_activities      id
1  '2014/10/11'  A   level1      20     10              1
2  '2014/10/11'  B   level1      20     10              2
3  '2014/10/11'  C   level1      10      9              3
4  '2014/10/11'  A   level2      5      12              4
5  '2014/10/11'  B   level2      6       5              5
6  '2014/10/11'  C   level2      7       8              6
7  '2014/10/11'  A   level3      7       8              7
8  '2014/10/11'  B   level3      9       5              8
9  '2014/10/11'  C   level3      20     23              9
101  '2014/11/27'  A   level33     20     10              101
102  '2014/11/27'  B   level33     30     10              102
103  '2014/11/27'  C   level33     10      9              103
104  '2014/11/27'  A   level34     10     12              104
105  '2014/11/27'  B   level34     16      5              105
106  '2014/11/27'  C   level34     5       8              106
107  '2014/11/27'  A   level35     3       8              107
108  '2014/11/27'  B   level35     1       5              108
109  '2014/11/27'  C   level35     10     23              109", header = T)
```

Comment: this is what I want but somehow I still get the same output as previously using my data:/

Comment: @Harper I suggest going through the code example I give step by step. That way you'll see exactly what every step does. I've included the sample data you give, so this is fully reproducible. It may be that you have different column names so you may need to make some adjustments for your bigger data.

Comment: I think it's because the time in excel is taking the datetime rather than just date. Thank you for your help. I will try to fix that.